# How to post/send an image to an API using Axios?

Tags: image, axios

I am trying to post/send an image to an API through `axios`.
Here is my frontend code (`ReactJS`):

```
const handleImage = (e) => {
    const myImg = e.target.files[0];

    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
    };

    if (myImg !== undefined) {
        let form = new FormData();

        form.append("file", myImg);

        axios.post("/upload", form, config)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

Here is my backend code (`NodeJS` & `ExpressJS`):

```
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

`console.log(req.body)` printing an empty object i.e. `{}` on console window.
So, in short, my doubt is why its printing an empty object? Is there something that I am missing in my code?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because your backend is not ready to receive files upload.

You can use a library called [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) which will make easier setting up your backend for supporting files upload.

There is a lot of content explaining how to use Multer. You can check [this one](https://medium.com/@svibhuti22/file-upload-with-multer-in-node-js-and-express-5bc76073419f) out